# How to ask about one's availability? "free/available/not busy"?

Tags: word-choice

Are the following equally appropriate to be used at work with a colleague or client? I don't want to be informal, but I don't have to be too formal either.

> Let me know when you are free so that
>   we can discuss this in more details.

or

> Let me know when you are available so that
>   we can discuss this in more details.

or

> Let me know when you are not busy so that
>   we can discuss this in more details.

*Disclaimer:* I'm not a native English speaker (as if I had to explain that)

Comment: Just thought I'd point out that you want "more detail" (singular) rather than "more details". (This isn't what you're asking about of course.)

Comment: Just to expand on @Noldorin's comment, I would also drop the word *more*, it's redundant. *…so that we can discuss this in detail.* It is also acceptable to drop the word "that," since *so* is used as a conjunction here. You would keep the word *more* only if you want to emphasize the fact that you've already had a substantial discussion.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All three variations of the sentence you give are grammatically correct, and are virtually (but not completely) equivalent. There are a few points worth noting in particular.

1. It is far more conventional to say "let me know when you are busy" than "let me know when you are *not* busy". The negative is considered redundant, and they are understood to mean the same thing, i.e. they are both enquiring about availability.
2. Saying `free` or `available` rather than `busy` may be considered a more "positive" enquiry. It may also simply mean that you *expect* the person to be busy rather than free, rather than the other way round.
3. Saying `available` rather than `free` is considered slightly more formal, though I wouldn't worry much about usage cases. (Most people wouldn't think twice if you used either in a formal or colloquial situation.)

Comment: ...grammatically correct *modulo replacing "details" with "detail".*

Comment: +1 For the comprehensive answer, but I feel obliged to note I have often asked people to give me a call when they're "not busy."

Comment: @Robusto: Oh indeed, that makes the most sense there. My comment was specific to "let me know ...".

Comment: @Martha: If you check my comment on the main post I've mentioned that. :)

Comment: @Martha (re your edit): What was wrong with "enquiry"?  In BrE we typically use "enquiry" in the general meaning of "question", while "inquiry" tends to be reserved for the sense of "formal investigation".

Comment: @Martha: Please don't be so quick to edit. I use British English, and do not at all appreciate when people who are not familiar with it pick an issue. The only other edit I saw you made is the removal of the comma; this "vocative" comma was quite grammatically correct.

Comment: Also, @Brian Nixon is absolutely right. We use both words; they mean slightly different things typically.

Comment: (I've deleted my comments about my edits, since they're no longer relevant.)

Answer (score 7):

All three of those are equally appropriate, and as far as I know, completely equivalent.  The only thing I would change would be to say "in more detail" rather than "in more details".